# Calling the R function .C() continually with static vectors, do you need to keep coercing datatypes?

Tags: c, r, malloc, memory-corruption

I have googled this problem and looked in R extensions manual, but could find no information on it.

I have a reasonably large program which makes many calls to C code with .C. I am passing in quite a lot of data which doesn't change over the course of the program. I therefore decided to coerce them to the right datatype just once:

vec = as.integer(as.vector(vec)).

Then in the .C call I write:

.C('function', vec = vec)

as opposed to

.C('function', vec = as.integer(as.vector(vec))).

This was done as profiling revealed as.* was taking up a bit of time. However in doing this I get (after a few hundred thousand iterations) a glibc error in malloc:

*** glibc detected**  /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0cabc0d8 **

I am just curious as to why this happens, seeing as the object I coerced at the start does not change over the course of the program, and if there is a way to get around this so I can minimise my as.* calls.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You most probably just have a bug in your C function, or you try to free the integer vector that you got as argument, which you should not.
Anyway this must not be related to the fact that you pre-convert your vector.

How do you supply the length of your vector to your function ?

Comment: There cannot be a bug in my C code, as when I call it with.C('fn',i=as.integer(i)...) it runs perfectly, but when I do .C('fn', i=i) with predefining i=as.integer(i) it gives that error. I do not free anything that I do not malloc in C myself.
The length of the vector/matrices are predefined, and I pass them in as my example above.
Cheers.

Comment: Hi, first in my experience the problem is most often in our code, so saying the bug can not be in my C code is probably not the right mindset to solve the problem. It would help of course if you could reproduce the problem and with a minimal C function. Questions: 1) what the purpose of the vec argument ? It is a kind of temporary buffer ? 2) just to be clear: doing the same number of iterations with vec = as.integer(as.vector(vec)) does nor crash ? 3) have you looked at the core dump, or run under debugger to see where the memory fault happens ? Or use valgrind ?

Comment: 4) could you try adding the DUP=TRUE argument to .C to see if it still crashes ?

Comment: I have not run Valgrind, as the time it takes to get this error varies from 10,000 iterations to 300,000. These take some time (hence why I am writing in C) and using valgrind would slow it down a huge amount. However I can leave on on for weeks etc if nothing else will point to the problem. 

This code base I am co-developing is reasonably large (2009 paper Incorporating genotype uncertainty into mark-recapture-type models for estimating abundance using DNA samples) so the vectors/matrices that I pass in are usually integers or doubles. I will try DUP=TRUE and see if that effects it.
Thanks

Comment: 1: Just integers and doubles and vectors/matrices/lists of them, purpose varies..
2: Ranges from 10,000 to 300,000 iterations before error happens.
3: I have not run valgrind, as it slows it down so much it would take forever before it hits the error. I will look at running DDD.
Thanks for your continued help.